# How to read body of mail using javax.mail.internet.MimeMulitpart

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to read the body contents of a mail and i keep getting the following "Message" string...but not actual body of mail

SentDate : Mon May 21 14:56:47 CAT 2012
From : {FROM} 
Subject : TEST
Message :***javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@320e7a***

Any help/advice on what exactly it is i might be missing?
Thanking you in adnvance
Faheem

Answer (score 0):

A mail could be plain text, html or Multipart(text + attachments), Multipart Alternative(text + html) etc.
You have to iterate through each `BodyPart` to know it's type and then get the content accordingly. This javamail FAQ [entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody) could help you.